# Can not delete the address from the struct and array in JavaScript

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

My other functions are working so I guess other codes are fine. I am just getting this error after clicking the delete key:

```
"Error deleting patient: Error: invalid address
    at v (web3.min.js:2:4288)
    at l (web3.min.js:2:2260)
    at web3.min.js:2:14456
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at i.formatInput (web3.min.js:2:14429)
    at i.toPayload (web3.min.js:2:14658)
    at r.e [as sendTransaction] (web3.min.js:2:14964)
    at c.sendTransaction (web3.min.js:2:6896)
    at c.execute (web3.min.js:2:7725)
    at truffle-contract.js:190:16"
```

This is my Solidity Function:

```
function deletePatient(string memory _patientAddressString) public onlyAdmin {
        address patientAddress = address(bytes20(bytes(_patientAddressString)));
        // Deleting patient data from the patients mapping
        delete patients[patientAddress];
        
        // Deleting patient address from the patientAddresses array
        for (uint i = 0; i < patientAddresses.length; i++) {
            if (patientAddresses[i] == patientAddress) {
                for (uint j = i; j < patientAddresses.length - 1; j++) {
                    patientAddresses[i] = patientAddresses[i + 1];
                }
                patientAddresses.pop();
            }
        }
            patientCount--;
        }
```

And this is my JavaScript function:

```
handleDeleteClick: async function(patientAddress) {
  console.log('Delete clicked for patient:', patientAddress);
  const instance = await App.contracts.PatientManagement.deployed();
  if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${patientAddress} information?`)) {
    try {
      const deleteTx = await instance.deletePatient(patientAddress);
      console.log(`${patientAddress} deleted successfully. Transaction hash: ${deleteTx.tx}`);
      App.AllPatients();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting patient:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`Deletion canceled`);
  }
},
```

The Solidity function works fine in Remix IDE
One thing to note is that the first console log is running. I am quite new in this community and new to JavaScript and Solidity. Please support me and be kind. Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you sending the address as `string memory`? It would be better to send it as address directly.